Automate print pdf using robot framework
I am using windows. My application has a print icon. On click of that print icon opens the send to print window. How to automate this print window.
I already tried below steps but nothing worked so far. The focus never goes to this print window. Please guide.
Click Element    my-print-icon-id

Switch Window    NEW

Click Element    print-screen-print-button-id


Hey @Anna, not sure what RF libraries you are using but quick google search gave me these results: Unable to click on the Print button in chrome browser and Print dialog not able to handle. If these don't help, then feel free to ask this question in the forum too.

@Pramesh I have already tried both the link, no suggested solution works.

I managed to save the pdf via print window, using the SikuliLibrary. Here is the Robot code.
demo.robot:
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           SikuliLibrary    mode=new
Library           OperatingSystem

Suite Setup       SikuliLibrary.Start Sikuli Process
Suite Teardown    SikuliLibrary.Stop Remote Server

*** Variables ***
${PATH}           C:\\Development
${URL}            https://wcmshelp.ucsc.edu/advanced/print-button.html
${PRINTBTN}       //button[.='Print this page']

*** Test Cases ***
print_try
    SeleniumLibrary.Open Browser                     ${URL}    browser=chrome
    SeleniumLibrary.Maximize Browser Window
    SeleniumLibrary.Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${PRINTBTN}
    Repeat Keyword                                   21 times    Press Key(s)    TAB
    Repeat Keyword                                   2 times     Press Key(s)    ENTER    delay=3
    SikuliLibrary.Input Text                         ${EMPTY}    ${PATH}\\my_file.pdf
    Sleep    2s
    Press Key(s)                                     ENTER       delay=2                
    SeleniumLibrary.Close Browser
    OperatingSystem.File Should Exist                path=${PATH}\\my_file.pdf

*** Keywords ***
Press Key(s)
    [Arguments]                   ${KEY}    ${delay}=0
    SikuliLibrary.Key Down        ${KEY}
    SikuliLibrary.Key Up          ${KEY}
    Sleep                         ${delay}

I also tried SeleniumLibrary.Click Element    ${PRINTBTN} but SikuliLibrary did not interact with the print window unfortunately. For some reason it works if Print this page button is pressed by simulating the TAB button. Additionally, I added OperatingSystem.File Should Exist keyword to make sure file is present in the folder. I hope this helps.

And if you want to change the print destination, then you can send the TAB key multiple times on the print window.
